# Dice rolling game simulator

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am building a dice game and I need to incorporate two dice instead of one. I was using roll = r.nextInt(12)+2; but that will not give me the same odds as rolling two separate dice. I changed my randoms below but now it doubles the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class W7KyleAbel 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Utilities
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    // Variables
    int numberOfrolls = 0;
    int rollOne = 0;
    int rollTwo = 0;
    int [] count = new int [12];

    //Welcome Statement
    System.out.println("Welcome to the dice throwing simulator!");

    //Get the number of rolls from the user
    System.out.println("How many dice rolls would you like to simulate?");
    numberOfrolls = in.nextInt();

    //Simulate the number of rolls
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfrolls; i++)
    {
        rollOne = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        rollTwo = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        count[rollOne+rollTwo]++;
    } //end for

    //Iterate through the list of rolled counts & histogram
    for(int i = 1; i < count.length; i++)
    {
        StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer(100 * count[i] / numberOfrolls);
        for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
        {
            outputBuffer.append("*");
        }//end for
        System.out.println((i+1)+ ":" + outputBuffer);
    }//end for

    //Results
    System.out.println("DICE ROLLING SIMULATION RESULTS\n" +
            "Each \"*\" represents 1% of the total number of rolls.\n" +
            "Total number of rolls = "+ numberOfrolls + ".");
```

}
}

Comment: Surely you meant to write `count[rollOne+rollTwo]++;` right?

Comment: Or `count[rollOne+rollTwo-1]++;`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Since `1<=rollOne<=6` and `1<=rollTwo<=6` I think you need `count[rollOne+rollTwo-1]++;`: then `count[i]` will represent the number of times a total of `i+1` was thrown with the two dice.

Answer (score -1):

As what David Wallance said, the sum of both dices can be achieved by this.

```
count[rollOne+rollTwo+1]++;
```

Tried the code with a thousand simulation with no problems.

Comment: Not even an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I would have thought you'd get at least one 11 or 12 in one thousand rolls...

Comment: @James_D Nope, i used his codes just replaced the 2 counts with the one mentioned and results are alright.

Comment: @James_D I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I put in an amount higher than 10. Ex 100 or 1000. Do you have any idea why it will work for a lower amount?

Comment: You declared `int[] count = new int[12];`. So `count` has 12 elements, indexed `0, 1, 2, ..., 11`. If the total `rollOne+rollTwo` is `11`, then you are trying to index element `rollOne+rollTwo+1`, which is `12`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: That's weird, it's working find on mine though..
[link](http://pastebin.com/MFYb8LV4)
Maybe i edited something and forgot.